# BPMN Intermediate Events Attached to an Activity Boundary

Tags: bpmn

how would you drow diagram - example A or Example B or both are fine? In Example A there is an event, one extra task and process is back in the main flow. Example B - if the event occurs process is not back in main flow. Is it correct to draw process like in example A? Examples enclosed. Thank you in advance for help. [image: BPMN events]

I draw examples (enclosed) and checked in BPMN specification but still have doubs.

Answer (score 1):

I would go a step further and put a gateway in front of "Application Analysis" and then draw the arrow from the message event to that gateway (so the gateway is only used to join, doesn't need a condition, it is best practice, you could draw the arrow from the message event directly back on the task itself and it would express the same thing).

The basic reasoning is that you shouldn't have multiple tasks for the same thing in the diagram unless it is really at a different stage in the workflow.

However it isn't exactly the same as your workflow, because like this the customer could change the loan amount multiple times and not just once.

There are some problems:

1. I think you want to make the message event interrupting, otherwise you grant both loans, the original one and the changed one.
2. After "Application Analysis" there should probably be a gateway that checks the result of the analysis and only if it was ok you grant the loan.